# how to get the current MTU in python using dbus/bluez

Tags: python, dbus, bluez

Is there a way to attain the current client connection's MTU in python using dbus bluez?

if I watch `btmon` I can see the value (503) after connection:

```
# btmon | grep MTU
  ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
    Client RX MTU: 517
  ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
    Server RX MTU: 517
  ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
    Client RX MTU: 503
  ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
    Server RX MTU: 517
```

however there seems to be no handle to this value within the dbus.bluez api

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this, but you can try to use the experimental WriteValue method it returns raw file descriptor and MTU. See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Comment: looks like a very useful document! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bluez does not expose MTU size on dbus api. However this information is given in the Read, Write, etc callbacks in the options parameter.

```
        Methods     array{byte} ReadValue(dict options)

        Issues a request to read the value of the
        characteristic and returns the value if the
        operation was successful.

        Possible options: "offset": uint16 offset
                  "mtu": Exchanged MTU (Server only)
                  "device": Object Device (Server only)
```